# CATS plugin blender problem

Tags: error

[image: picture of decimaion failure]

so I'm still working on the speaker, I got textures working. and now I'm trying the CATS quick decimation. but when I try it gives the error "No meshes found!" some help?

Comment: Try Adding an MMD model under the armatures and use the Attach Mesh Option in the custom model creation. I did that, got an error, but it let me decimate after that.